# How fix "No rule to make target 'arch/arm64/boot/dts/kona-rumi.dtb', needed by '__build'. Stop

Tags: kernel, compiling, android

Previously, I had the same error related to the file: `arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom/apq8016-sbc.dtb`, but I solved it by deleting the line `subdir-y += qcom` from the `arch/arm64/boot/dts/Makefile`.
Now a new same error appears and I have no idea how to fix it.
Internet advice didn't help.

Error:

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm64/boot/dts/kona-rumi.dtb', needed by '__build'. Stop.
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [../scripts/Makefile.build:642: arch/arm64/boot/dts] Error 2
make[1]: *** [arch/arm64/Makefile:172: dtbs] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Error with `make V=1`:

```
make -f ../scripts/Makefile.build obj=arch/arm64/boot/dts/ti need-builtin=
(cat /dev/null; ) > arch/arm64/boot/dts/ti/modules.order
make -f ../scripts/Makefile.build obj=arch/arm64/boot/dts/vendor need-builtin=
make -f ../scripts/Makefile.build obj=arch/arm64/boot/dts/vendor/qcom need-builtin=
(cat /dev/null; ) > arch/arm64/boot/dts/vendor/qcom/modules.order
make[4]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm64/boot/dts/vendor/qcom/kona-rumi.dtb', needed by '__build'.  Stop.
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [../scripts/Makefile.build:642: arch/arm64/boot/dts/vendor/qcom] Error 2
make[2]: *** [../scripts/Makefile.build:642: arch/arm64/boot/dts/vendor] Error 2
make[1]: *** [arch/arm64/Makefile:172: dtbs] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

MyKernel:

[kernel](https://github.com/OnePlusOSS/android_kernel_oneplus_sm8250/tree/oneplus/SM8250_R_11.0)

My build code:

```bash
export ARCH=arm64
export SUBARCH=arm64
export HEADER_ARCH=arm64
export DTC_EXT=dtc
PATH="/home/hehe/Downloads/clang/bin:/home/hehe/Downloads/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin:/home/hehe/Downloads/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/bin:${PATH}"
rm -rf out
make O=out clean && make mrproper
make O=out ARCH=arm64 kona_defconfig
make -j$(nproc --all) O=out ARCH=arm64 CC=clang CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android- CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32=arm-linux-androideabi-
```

Comment: Hi, if you call make with `make V=1` (verbose) it can give you more info. Maybe it helps you. If you add the output to your question, it maybe can help others to solve it.

Comment: @PaulSmith Thanks, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need  device tree of kona/sm8250 device brother, see in oneplus oss, like other vendor they not include that in kernel but in other repo like device tree,
after that vendor device tree moved to kernelsource/arch/arm64/boot/dts (vendor) here